# Mongodb error in creating user in version 2.6.4

Tags: mongodb

Mongodb not allowing to add the user. Version am using is 2.6.4.

Here is the step I have followed:

```
root@prd-app-mongodb-replicaset-s01:/home/vijay# mongo admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: admin
> db.createUser({user: "xxxx",pwd: "xxxxx",roles: [ "root" ]});
2014-08-12T09:42:26.480-0700 Error: couldn't add user: not master at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

Comment: Try adding the user in the primary. The error message looks like you are trying to add the user on the secondary.

Comment: If you see the prompt, the replica set is **not even initiated** so who's to say primary or secondary ? I also got this with 3.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/ doesn't say I have to *initiate the replica set first*.

But the *workaround* is:

```
rs.initiate();
db.createUser({db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "secret",
    roles: [{role: "root", db: "admin"}]});
```

Then it will work.